# How to get Value of Password input Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function with input var is name of Form and ID of input. Now I want to get the value of password input. The problem is I have some input with same ID but in different form. So I want a flexible way to get its value when I know its form.

I have tried
`var x = Form_Name.ID_Name.value;`

but it doesn't work. So please tell me how to get the value of password input by a flexible way. Thanks so much. Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="lolkittens" />
    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
        function check(Form_Name, ID_Name)
        {
            alert(document.getElementById(ID_Name).value);
            alert(Form_Name);
            var x = Form_Name.ID_Name.value;
            alert(x);
        }
    </script>
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
        <form name="MainForm" id="MainForm">
            <input id="ID" name="ID" type="text" size="20"/>
            <input id="Pass" name="Pass" type="password" size="20"/>
        </form>
        <button value="click Me" onclick="check('MainForm','ID')"> Click Me </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To get password value, you can use `document.getElementById('Pass').value`

Comment: Use regular DOM methods like `document.getElementById()`, `document.getElementsByTagName()`, etc. Exposing every item as a global variable is something you can expect in Internet Explorer 4 but not in modern browsers.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález where do you see global variables ? `Form_Name` is a string .. also `console.log(Pass.value);` work in latest chrome

Comment: @Hacketo I thought the intention of `Form_Name.ID_Name.value` might be that even though the call passes a string.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I guess you're right about the intention, but this way work in modern browsers (at least on my chrome and firefox). this work `console.log(window[Form_Name][ID_Name].value);`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Thanks so much. I fixed it like this and it work: 
var x = window[Form_Name][ID_Name].value;
alert(x);

The problem is I have some input with same ID but in different form. So I want a flexible way to get its value when I know its form.

Answer (score 4):

I have created another button for you to get password.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="lolkittens" />
    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
        function check(Form_Name, ID_Name)
        {
            alert(document.getElementById(ID_Name).value);
        }
    </script>
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
        <form name="MainForm" id="MainForm">
            <input id="ID" name="ID" type="text" size="20"/>
            <input id="Pass" name="Pass" type="password" size="20"/>
        </form>
        <button value="click Me" onclick="check('MainForm','ID')"> Click Me for ID </button>
        <button value="click Me" onclick="check('MainForm','Pass')"> Click Me for Password</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Optimized way:
>   You can achieve it using the same button as well, by passing an array of ID's.

Let me know, I can help more on this.

Comment: it would help OP to remove the useless code, and explain what is wrong with `Form_Name.ID_Name.value`

Comment: Yes rightly pointed out. editing the code to remove useless code.

Comment: @bozzmob:  Thanks so much. I fixed it like this and it work: var x = window[Form_Name][ID_Name].value; alert(x); The problem is I have some input with same ID but in different form. So I want a flexible way to get its value when I know its form.

Comment: @bozzmob: Is ` <meta name="author" content="lolkittens" />` useful code?

Answer (score 2):

Access username and password using it's id.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="lolkittens" />
    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
        function check()
        {
            var username = document.getElementById("ID").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("Pass").value;
            alert("Username: "+username+"  Password: "+password);
        }
    </script>
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
        <form name="MainForm" id="MainForm">
            <input id="ID" name="ID" type="text" size="20"/>
            <input id="Pass" name="Pass" type="password" size="20"/>
        </form>
        <button value="click Me" onclick="check()"> Click Me </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```